# How do you return an Observable of an object where the object has a property built using an http request? [RxJs]

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a type I want to return from a method that is not the same as one the http request gets - I basically want to assign the results of that http request as a property on the object and return an observable of that object. I understand why the below is not going to work but for the purposes of having code..

```
getAuditsByObjectAndType<T>(object: T): Observable<IAuditInformation<T>> {
    const auditInfo: IAuditInformation<T> = {
        audits: [],
        object: object
    };

    auditInfo.audits = this.get<IAudit>(`audits?id=${object.id}`)
    return Observable.of(auditInfo)
}
```

Is there an operator that will help me do what I want please?

Edit:

Got a working implementation but probably could be a lot better..

```
getAuditsByObjectAndType<T>(object: T): Observable<IAuditInformation<T>> {
    const auditInfo: Observable<IAuditInformation<T>> = Observable.of({
        audits: [],
        object: object
    });

    return this.get<IAudit>(`AuditItems?id=${object.id}`)
        .combineLatest(auditInfo, (audits, info) => {
            info.audits = audits;
            return info
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the response:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

getAuditsByObjectAndType<T>(object: T): Observable<IAuditInformation<T>> {
  return this.get<IAudit>(`audits?id=${object.id}`)
    .map(audits => ({
      audits,
      object
    }));
}
```

However typescript has no way of knowing that your `T` contains an `id` property, to solve that you could do the following:

```ts
interface TheObjectWithAnId {
  id: number;
}

getAuditsByObjectAndType<T extends TheObjectWithAnId>(object: T): Observable<IAuditInformation<T>>
```

Comment: This will return many observables with the object in each one though right?

Comment: This will return one observable with one object and the result of the HTTP request (which I'm assuming is an array). If this is incorrect you may need to show an example of your data structure and describe what you want it to return.

Comment: wow I am so dumb - because the observable stream will emit once, with a value that is an array this will of course work. I got it into my head that stream would emit once for each item in the array. Thanks man.

Comment: Not instantly knowing how every library behaves is not being dumb, simply acknowledging that you don't know and asking the question shows intelligence.